# Snowplow Analytics `uid` GET param does not appear

Tags: http, snowplow

I have the Snowplow event tracker snippet included on my website using Google Tag Manager, and Snowplow events are indeed being sent as GET requests to the endpoint I've configured. Many of the params from the [Snowplow tracker protocol](https://github.com/snowplow/snowplow/wiki/snowplow-tracker-protocol) are present in the requests. However, I used

`window.snowplow('setUserId', 'XXXX');`

in the Tag to set the `uid` param, but it doesn't appear in the request. How can I enable it?

The Snowplow documentation implies this event is included automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try Modify the name "snowplow_name_here" ,some words not working.
example, if your name , start with "option", don't work.